# No route matches [GET] "/auth/twitter/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I have a classic omniauth problem, when trying to access the '/auth/twitter'.

The problem with the other solutions out there is that I can't remove :omniauthable from user.rb, because the facebook authentication won't work.

Also, If I remove the devise lines below, the twitter authentication works. It seems that there is a compatibility problem between twitter and facebook with omniauth, does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

**devise.rb**

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
```

**Gemfile**

```
# Users from facebook
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

**omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger 

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :confirmable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using OmniAuth with Devise, you have to configure OmniAuth providers in the `devise.rb` file.

So you should configure the `omniauth-twitter` gem like you are already configuring the `omniauth-facebook` gem:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :facebook, "FACEBOOK_KEY", "FACEBOOK_SECRET"
  config.omniauth :twitter, "TWITTER_KEY", "TWITTER_SECRET"
end
```

You can also remove the following from your code:

1. The `omniauth` gem in your `Gemfile`.
2. The `require "omniauth-facebook"` statement in your `devise.rb` file.
3. The `omniauth_providers: [:facebook]` hash in your `user.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked in the most part, except I changed link_to [...], 'auth/twitter' into link_to [...], user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) .